# remove duplicate elements from list without creating new list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, duplicates

I'm trying to remove an element from a list using for loops (without creating new list or functions like set()..etc)

I wrote the below code but I got: IndexError: list index out of range.

what I missing?

```
MyList=[1,1,2,3]

for i in MyList:
   for j in MyList:
      if MyList[i] == MyList[j]:
         del MyList[j]
      else:
         j = j+1
         i = i+1

print(MyList)
```

I expect to get same list without duplicate elements

Comment: Will the list always be sorted?

Comment: A problem is that you are iterating through the list with a for loop and deleting elements on the fly - which messes up your for loop. Everytime you delete an element, you must restart your for loop or maybe just keep track of the indexes and delete them all at the end.

Comment: Try to run and debug it here -https://pythontutor.com/   IT's easier to find out in the visual platform.

Comment: I saw that you have written that you don't want use functions e.g. `set`, but could you add the reason why don't you like using builtin functions? That could make easier to provide further support.
If you just want to avoid introducing new variables/functions, you can always delete them by using `del` statement :) P.S. Removing duplicate elements without using any builtin/custom functions nor additional variables will be a pretty hard task.

Comment: You’re indexing the list with its own elements…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an indexing error because you are using item values as indexes. `for i in myList:` places item values (not indexes) in the `i` variable.  So using `i` as an index in `MyList[i] == MyList[j]` cannot work.

In order to get indexes, you need to use the `range()` or `enumerate()` function (or increase a variable manually).

One way to avoid interference of removals on the list iteration is to work your way backward.

For example (using your own indexing variable):

```
i = len(myList)-1             # current item index (starting from last)
for n in reversed(myList):    # iterate backward
    if myList.index(n) < i:   # if n is duplicate of earlier item
        del myList[i]         #    remove the duplicate
    i -= 1                    # previous index
```

Another approach could be to move items that are not duplicates at the beginning of the list and delete the extra positions at the end of the loop:

```
j = 0                          # next position of unique item
for n in myList:               # go through items
    if myList.index(n) >= j:   # not already at beginning of list
        myList[j] = n          # place it at beginning 
        j += 1                 # next unique position
myList[j:] = []                # delete extra space
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
MyList=[1, 1, 2, 3]

    for number in MyList:
        repeated = MyList.count(number)
        if repeated > 1:
            MyList.remove(number)
    print(MyList)
```

The result will be: [1, 2, 3]

Comment: This will not work when iteration over MyList is made to skip items because of removals within the loop.  For example: [2, 3, 2, 3, 2] --> [3, 3, 2]